# What is the actual range of Xbee RP-SMA antenna?

Tags: xbee

I'm building a Model rocket, and i will use xbee series 1 pro, so i think RP-SMA antenna would be the best to use because i will put the xbee into the rocket. So does anyone know what is the range of the xbee with this antenna? 
Can it reach 1000 feet?

Comment: At https://www.sparkfun.com/pages/xbee_guide there is a table containing the ranges of the different models. I think your model says 1 Mile. Though these rating are probably very optimistic.